# Find duplicates in pandas and modify them by date with non Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to find the duplicates based on Color and Price. Then change the code with the code of the most recent(based on the Date) row, that doesn't have a Nan value in Detail column. I don't want any row to be deleted. The dataframe is this:

```
id   Color   Price   Code       Date          Detail
1   White    1.50     111   3-22-2017 12:00    aa
2   Green    2.20     222   3-23-2017 09:55    bb
3   Black    3.00     333   3-24-2017 11:45    cc
4   White    1.50     111   3-23-2017 10:20    Nan
5   White    1.50     444   3-23-2017 08:15    ee
6   Green    2.20     555   3-25-2017 07:05    ff
```

the result should be this:

```
id   Color   Price   Code       Date           Detail
 1   White    1.50    *444*   3-22-2017 12:00   aa
 2   Green    2.20    *555*   3-23-2017 09:55   bb
 3   Black    3.00     333    3-24-2017 11:45   cc
 4   White    1.50    *444*   3-23-2017 10:20   Nan
 5   White    1.50     444    3-23-2017 08:15   ee
 6   Green    2.20     555    3-25-2017 07:05   ff
```

This code does the half job, it doesn't consider the Detail column. So, what should I change? Maybe use notnull() ?

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Code'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Color', 'Price'])['Code'].transform('last')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), because [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) cannot working with 2 columns in one time.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

def f(x):
    a = x.loc[x['Detail'].notnull(), 'Code']
    #added if-else because no match return error in iat (iloc) functions 
    x['Code'] = np.nan if a.empty else a.iat[-1]
    return x

df = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Color', 'Price'], sort=False).apply(f).sort_index()
print (df)
   id  Color  Price  Code                Date Detail
0   1  White    1.5   444 2017-03-22 12:00:00     aa
1   2  Green    2.2   555 2017-03-23 09:55:00     bb
2   3  Black    3.0   333 2017-03-24 11:45:00     cc
3   4  White    1.5   444 2017-03-23 10:20:00    NaN
4   5  White    1.5   444 2017-03-23 08:15:00     ee
5   6  Green    2.2   555 2017-03-25 07:05:00     ff
```

Comment: If check in function `print (x.loc[x['Detail'].notnull(), 'Code'].tail(1))` it return `scalar`s ?

Comment: Is it easy to add this changes as a new column 'New_Codes' and keep the old one 'Code' as it was at first?

Comment: sure, change `x['Code'] = np.nan if a.empty else a.iat[-1]` to `x['New_Codes'] = np.nan if a.empty else a.iat[-1]`